# Fetching information from the different links on a web page and writing them to a .xls file using pandas,bs4 in Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner to Python Programming. I am practicing web scraping using bs4 module in python.

I have extracted some fields from a web page but it is extracting only 13 items whereas the web page has more than 13 items. I cannot understand why are the rest of the items not extracted.

Another thing is I want to extract the contact number and the email address of each item on the web page but they are available in the item's respective links. I am a beginner and frankly speaking I got stuck to how to access and scrape the link of each item's individual web page within a given web page. Kindly tell where am I doing wrong and if possible suggest what is to be done.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd


res = requests.post('https://www.nelsonalexander.com.au/real-estate-agents/?office=&agent=A')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"agent-card large large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns text-center end"})

records = []

for item in data:
    name = item.find('h2').text.strip()
    position = item.find('h3').text.strip()
    records.append({'Names': name, 'Position': position})

df = pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['Names','Position'])
df=df.drop_duplicates()
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\laptop\Desktop\NelsonAlexander.xls', sheet_name='MyData2', index = False, header=True)
```

I have done the above code for just extracting the names and the position of each items but it only scrapes 13 records but there are more records than it in the web page. I could not write any code for extracting the contact number and the email address of each record because it is present inside each item's individual page as I have got stuck.

The Excel sheet looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The website is making new requests and adding new people as the user scrolls the window. requests and bs4 only capture the first 13 because thats the number shown by default, since no scrolling is happening. I suggest you use Selenium.

Comment: The web page you're scraping has infinite scrolling i.e. will load more results when you get to the bottom of the page. Your request will only return the initial set of results. Requests isn't able to mimic this behaviour. I advise using something like selenium and headless chrome to scrape that page.

Comment: This might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868356/using-python-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-to-scrape-for-content-of-a-tag/51871396

Comment: Okay, then I have to learn Selenium. But what about accessing and scraping the Contact number and the email of each item which is present inside the item's individual web page. Kindly say if I am stating wrong and if possible suggest what can be done?

Comment: You cannot retrieve the email, as the website makes the user fill a form which it sends from the backend. However, you can extract the telephone, by fetching the anchor tags and then getting their attribute value using `.get('href')`.

Answer (score 0):

That website is loading the list dynamically as you scroll, however you can trace the `ajax` request, and parse data directly:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0', 'Referer': 'https://www.nelsonalexander.com.au/real-estate-agents/?office=&agent=A'}
records = []

with requests.Session() as s:

    for i in range(1, 22):

        res = s.get(f'https://www.nelsonalexander.com.au/real-estate-agents/page/{i}/?ajax=1&agent=A', headers=headers)
        soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

        data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"agent-card large large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns text-center end"})

        for item in data:
            name = item.find('h2').text.strip()
            position = item.find('h3').text.strip()
            phone = item.find("div",{"class":"small-6 columns text-left"}).find("a").get('href').replace("tel:", "")
            records.append({'Names': name, 'Position': position, 'Phone': phone})

df = pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['Names','Position', 'Phone'])
df=df.drop_duplicates()
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\laptop\Desktop\NelsonAlexander.xls', sheet_name='MyData2', index = False, header=True)
```

Comment: I was thinking of approaching the problem the same way, however, is there any dynamic way of determining the end page? Here you have gone through 22 pages.

Comment: Okay but from where can I get the ajax request and if I want to find the Contact number and the email address then how can it be accessed and scrape the  Contact number and the email address of each item which is present inside the item's individual web page. If  possible kindly suggest what can be done?

Comment: @Jibin Joseph I'm afraid not...the change that can be made is change the `for` loop to a `while` loop and simply `break` the loop once the `bs` element is `None`..

Comment: @ag2019 I've edited the post to include phone number... And you can track `ajax` requests by opening the browser developer tools.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. But if each of the item is clicked individually and in their respective web page if  the inspect tool is used, the contact number and the email address is available. I want to know how to access this web page and scrape the contact information if at all it is possible

Comment: @ag2019 Then in each iteration you need to query each individual page and search for the additional content that you want..

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that the emails are no where in the DOM. I made some modification to @drec4s code to instead go until there are no entries (dynamically).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import itertools

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0', 'Referer': 'https://www.nelsonalexander.com.au/real-estate-agents/?office=&agent=A'}
records = []

with requests.Session() as s:


    for i in itertools.count():

        res = s.get('https://www.nelsonalexander.com.au/real-estate-agents/page/{}/?ajax=1&agent=A'.format(i), headers=headers)
        soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

        data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"agent-card large large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns text-center end"})
        if(len(data) > 0):
            for item in data:
                name = item.find('h2').text.strip()
                position = item.find('h3').text.strip()
                phone = item.find("div",{"class":"small-6 columns text-left"}).find("a").get('href').replace("tel:", "")
                records.append({'Names': name, 'Position': position, 'Phone': phone})
                print({'Names': name, 'Position': position, 'Phone': phone})
        else:
            break
```